# Is using gcc implementation of vstring.h safe?

Tags: gcc, vstring

Reading the documentation and posts here in SO regarding the `gcc` extension `vstring.h` I am not sure if it can be used in a production environment or it has an *experimental* status.

**My question:**

Is it safe to use `vstring.h` in a production environment?